# What does this css declaration mean - two declarations at once

Tags: html, css

Can you please explain me this kind of css declaration:

```
.menu_blueSkin_Middle.dir_left div.align_left {
float: left;
 }
```

As far as i know if you have **.someName{}** it means that this is put in the html element class attribute. For example:

```
 <div class='someName'></div>.
```

But the example that brings the question has two dots. One in the begining and one in the middle. Then there is space and another declaration div.align_left?

Please give me some explanation!

Comment: 10x. I was wondering how to search for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.menu_blueSkin_Middle.dir_left div.align_left
```

There are three classes called here.

It's a bit complicated because whoever named these classes is an amateur. You should never name classes same as the css code.

To make it easier to understand, let's rename the three classes displayed:

- **menu_blueSkin_Middle** we will rename to **.firstclass**
- **dir_left** we will rename to **.secondclass**
- **.align_left** we will rename to **.thirdclass**

---

ok, now with the three renamed classes, lets show you the code:

```
.firstclass.secondclass div.thirdclass {
     float: left;
}
```

---

Ok so the following applies:

- .thirdclass is the only one being affected [with the float:left;
  code].
- Only .thirdclass classes within a div will be affected. (due to the div being located before it)
- Only .thirdclass div located within a class with double declaration of both .secondclass and .firstclass will be affected.

Example code:

```
<div class="firstclass secondclass">
    <p class="thirdclass">
    </p>
       <!-- NOTE: THIS IS JUST A NOTE SO YOU KNOW WHICH IS AFFECTED.
            The DIV below is the **only one affected**. The P above is NOT affected. Because it is not a DIV.
            The DIV at the bottom is NOT affected. Because it is not nested inside the firstclass secondclass 
       -->
    <div class="thirdclass">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="thirdclass">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Two dots indicate two classes - those particular CSS rules will only take effect if an element has both those classes.

Both of these classes need to be present on your outer div:

```
.menu_blueSkin_Middle .dir_left
```

While your class on the inside div should contain a div with the class (it can have more than one, but atleast the following):

```
.align_left
```

Therefore it should look something like this:

```
<div class="menu_blueSkin_Middle dir_left"> <!-- Outer div class selectors -->
    <div class="align_left"></div> <!-- Inner div class selector -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It means the element must have both classes to match the rule.

```
<div class="menu_blueSkin_Middle dir_left">
    <div class="align_left"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The div.align_left is a descendant selector. It means only apply (select) DOM elements of div.align_left that are nested in menu_blueskin_Middle.dor_left elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can have more than one class name in the `class` attribute of an element, and a selector with two class names put together means that the element needs to have both class names to match the selector.

The selector would for example match the inner `div` in this code:

```
<div class="menu_blueSkin_Middle dir_left">
  <div class="align_left"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It applies the contained rule to elements which have both classes assigned.

[Here's a sample](http://jsfiddle.net/uM4TR/)

```
<html>
  <style>
    .one { color: green; }
    .two { color:red; }
    .one.two { color:blue; }
  </style>
  <div class="one">I'll be Green</div>
  <div class="two">I'll be Red</div>
  <div class="one two">I'll be Blue</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.menu_blueSkin_Middle.dir_left div.align_left
```

means

any element with the class menu_blueSkin_Middle AND class dir_left, that has a child element that is a div tag that has the class align_left

Answer (score 0):

This is called double class selectors. It will be applied to an element having both classes, like one below

```
<div class="menu_blueSkin_Middle dir_left">...</div>
```

You can join any number of ID and class selectors like .class1#identifier.class2.class3 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of answers on what, but why?

```
.menu_blueSkin_Middle.dir_left div.align_left {
float: left;
 }
```

Sometimes you want to have more specificity (read that as a higher priority and adding two classes does that (no space between classes) - here you really have multiple which increases the likelihoods that this CSS will be applied.  SO that element that has those multiple classes gains specificity.

Try a search google/bing on  "css selectors multiple classes"